# Declare Submenu in GLUT?

Tags: c++, glut

In main function, when I declared submenu I got Two error.

the first error in   `GLint subMenu;` it says "GLint subMenu' previously declared here"

The other error on   `int subMenu;` it show that "redeclaration of 'int subMenu'

Here is a part of main function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);


     GLint subMenu;

    int subMenu;
    subMenu = glutCreateMenu (c_SubMenu);
    glutAddMenuEntry ("Red", 3);
    glutAddMenuEntry ("Green", 2);
    glutAddMenuEntry ("Blue", 1);
    glutAddMenuEntry ("White", 4);


}
```

Could any one explain how to declare Glint variable and int in the same time in order to solve this issue.

**EDIT :** even though I choose one of the variable name, I got error on `glutAddMenuEntry` it says "

> undefined reference to `_imp__glutAddMenuEntry@8'

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 variables have the same name. C++ doesn't allow to declare 2 variables with the same name even if they don't have the same type.

Comment: even though  I choose one of the variable name, I got error on {glutAddMenuEntry} it says "undefined reference to `_imp__glutAddMenuEntry@8'"

Comment: This is a complete different problem 
Have you set the linker for your library correctly? 
How do you compile your program?